# Difficulty with BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger, factorial

I am trying to do Factorial with Recursion and BigIntegers but eclipse is complaining about the BigInteger. I know the program is supposed to be simple but it is giving me headache. Here is the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Factorial
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter integer");
        BigInteger n = input.nextBigInteger();
        System.out.println("Factorial of " + n + " is "  + fact(n));

    }

    public static  int fact(BigInteger n)
    {
        if(n ==0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return n * fact(n-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`BigInteger` does not support comparison using `==` and multiplication using `*`. Instead, you have to call the appropriate methods of the `BigInteger` class ([`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`multipy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#multiply%28java.math.BigInteger%29)).

Also note that there exist [`BigInteger.ZERO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#ZERO) and [`BigInteger.ONE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#ONE).

Finally, the *return type* of your `fact` method should be `BigInteger` and not `int`. Whether you want the *argument* to be of type `BigInteger` or `int` is up to you.

Comment: Also, your `factorial` method should probably be accepting an `int` and returning a `BigInteger`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what @aix mentioned regarding invoking the arithmetics on `BigInteger` - I can also see another issue with this code.

Your method signature is

```
public static  int fact(BigInteger n)
```

This is problemantic - factorial grows fast, so you are very likely to overflow the result.

I *think* what you realy wanted is:

```
public static  BigInteger fact(int n)
```

which makes much more sense, since the return value should probably be the `BigInteger` (since it grows fast) and not the parameter, or possibly - both of them.

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't support operator overloading. So + and == can't be supported for user-defined classes with one exception that java.lang.String supports +.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't simply use arithmetic operator onto BigInteger object. Try to use their methods for arithmetic processes such as comparing, subtracting, multiplying etc.

References are given [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)