# Java BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [diffucilty with BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780209/diffucilty-with-biginteger)

```
import java.math.BigInteger;  
public class KillerCode{  
    public static void main(String[]args){  
        BigInteger sum=null;  
        for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++){        
            sum=sum+Math.pow(i, i);  
            System.out.println(sum);     
        }    
    }  
}
```

When I try to run this code the following error message is coming up.

> The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) BigInteger,double.

How can I solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Javadocs are you friend. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: Just to note, if this isn't for learning purposes, there's no reason to be using BigInteger in your case.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use the typical math operators with BigIntegers, check here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

you need to use `BigInteger.add(your numbers here)`

Further Explination,

```
sum = sum.add(new BigInteger(i).pow(i));
```

Comment: You also need to reinitialize sum to something, it can't just be null.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit???

Comment: @KillerCode Added what I think should solve your problem.

Comment: @Austin Sorry,it isn't working

Comment: @KillerCode What do you mean it isn't working? We need more information then that. Are you getting an error?

Comment: import java.math.BigInteger;
public class AWords{
 public static void main(String[]args){
  BigInteger sum=null;
  //BigInteger sum=new BigInteger(null);
  for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++){
   
   sum = sum.add(Math.pow(i, i));

   System.out.println(sum);
   
  }
     
  
 }
}

Comment: When I try this I got the following message.                            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method add(BigInteger) in the type BigInteger is not applicable for the arguments (double)

 at AWords.main(AWords.java:8)

Comment: @KillerCode I'm not by my computer at the moment so not sure, but I just edited again. Check to see if that works. If it doesn't, check the methods in the BigInteger javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it because *sum* is not an integer, but a reference to an object.

Unlike C++, java doesn't allow operator overloading, so you need to use the class methods to perform operations.

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize `sum` to a meaningful, NON-`null`, value (you current initialize to `null`):

   ```
   BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
   ```

   else the expression

   ```
   sum = sum.add(...)
   ```

   won't be meaningful (unless you *want* a `NullPointerException`).
2. Use the static factory `BigInteger.valueOf(long)` to map an integer value to a `BigInteger`.

   Don't use the expression `new BigInteger(i)`.  The constructor invoked by `new BigInteger(i)` is `BigInteger(byte[])`, with erroneous results (for your purposes) for values larger than 255 (which you have...).
3. Use `BigInteger.add(BigInteger)` for addition.
4. Use `BigInteger.pow(int)` instead of `Math.pow(int,int)`; since you're doing (Big) integer arithmetic, avoid anything that maps your work into the floating point world, i.e `double` or `float`, or you'll have lost the advantages of the `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger doesn't have a `+` operator defined. According to its [javadocs found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add%28java.math.BigInteger%29), you can use the .add() function to achieve the result you're seeking.